# Filter a managedQuery by file extension (or, alternatively, file type) for an Android Cursor

Tags: android, sql, cursor, projection, mediastore

I want to do a managedQuery using Android SDK where the results returned are filtered by their respective file *extension* (e.g. not the name, necessarily).  I've done quite a bit of researching and am tired and hoping the community can help me.. I'm sure the answer is out there but, in lieu of reading an SQL book or whatever, I'm just trying to do something that should be pretty simple but not finding the solution.

What I want to do is, essentially, something like:

```
managedQuery(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, myProjection, Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[] {"%mp3%"}, null );
```

This works EXCEPT that, if the title is something like "mymp3.wav", this query will still return it since 'mp3' is in the name but, that isn't what I want -> I want it filtered purely based on file extension (or, alternatively, file type if there is a way to do that [e.g. if an mp3's file extension name was changed to .wav even though the content of the file is actually mp3, that would work for my purposes as well]).  The solution should indicate a way to filter for multiple extensions/file types (i.e. if I want the query to return all .mp3 files as well as .wav files but not .amr files, for example).

Furthermore, while I have you, I want to sort the results alphabetically.  I have tried something like:

```
managedQuery(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, myProjection, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC" );
```

However, that doesn't filter the *entire* results... that is to say that, the list returned is sorted by, say, mp3 title and then, at the end, it then appends to the list the .wav files also sorted alphabetically but I want the entire list to be alphabetical regardless of file type.

I know someone on here can answer this easily -> thanks in advance!!!

Comment: what about if you put "." like {"%.mp3%"}?

Comment: I had tried %.mp3% before but, something else, syntactically, must have been off because it caused a crash but, now, yes, it works.... HOWEVER, how to make it work for %.mp3% AND %.wav% ???  (adding another string to the array doesn't work; it causes a crash with the message:
E/AndroidRuntime(9407): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: bind or column index out of range: handle 0x388060

Comment: Try this, managedQuery(Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, myProjection, Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", new String[] {"%.mp3","%.wav"}, null ); and let me know what happen.

Comment: no, that doesn't work.  I get the error mentioned in my prior comment...  But, I *love* the help!!!  Would love it even more if we could make it work  ;)

Comment: try the query Kurtis Nusbaum suggestted?

Comment: his updated answer worked... thanks very much to you both!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think all you have to do is change `%mp3%` to `%mp3`. This will force "mp3" to be at the end of the filename.

If you need to select multiple file types, do it like this:

```
managedQuery(
  Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
  myProjection, 
  Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? OR " + Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ", 
  new String[] {"%mp3","%wav"}, 
  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC" );
```

Comment: okay.  I think that that is a little bit better than putting %.mp3% as discussed in the comments above.  However, I *still* need to be able to have multiple selectionArgs (e.g. be able to have it return both .wav *and* .mp3 files) (and, preferably all sorted).  Do you have a solution?

Comment: Worked beautifully!!  Thanks for updating your answer!  I was trying Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? OR like ? "  to no avail; didn't think to try and add the second 'Audio.Media.DATA' in there.  THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!  (and thank you, user370305 as well for your help/diligence!)

Comment: Yea, it's kind of a bummer you have to add Audio.Media.DATA twice, but that's just the syntax of SQL for ya.

Comment: Okay, one final (I swear) question -> how to make the sort order 'MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC"' sort the resultant list in a case-insensitive fashion?  All my things that start with lower case 'a' are at the bottom of the things that start with upper case 'Z'... ???

Comment: @fatfreddyscat if you've got another question, please ask it as another question. That way other people who are searching for something similar in the future don't have to look at our back-and-forth in the comments...and so I can get more rep ;)

Comment: k... posted.  Go answer it to get your reputation on  :D