# How to filter more than 2 file type using managedQuery() in android?

Tags: android, filter, cursor

I tried the solution in the following link, It works for 2 file types
[Filter a managedQuery by file extension (or, alternatively, file type) for an Android Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932791/filter-a-managedquery-by-file-extension-or-alternatively-file-type-for-an-an?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Based on the solution for 2 file types, i tried with following code

```
String selectionMimeType = Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? OR " + Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? OR " + Audio.Media.DATA + "like ? ";

Cursor cursor = mFragment.getActivity().managedQuery(uri, null, selectionMimeType,  new String[] {"%mp3","%m4a","%wma"}, null);
```

Its crashing with log 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM audio WHERE (_data like ? OR _data like ? OR _datalike ? )

Comment: can you post your some code where you have get exception.

Comment: I have already posted i am getting exception in this line Cursor cursor = mFragment.getActivity().managedQuery(uri, null, selectionMimeType, new String[] {"%mp3","%m4a","%wma"}, null);

Comment: take a look at `OR _datalike ? )` part ... something is wrong ...

Comment: Thanks Selvin :) just a space before like solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a space before like `" like ? "` solved my issue